# Multiple condition in Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace my variable name in text file using regular expression with following condition :
let's take example that I want to replace `log` with `LOG`

1. If the line starts with `import` then I don't want to replace it. like `import com.test.log.myfile;` distance between import and log can be max up to 1000 → I don't want to replace here
2. If it is contained within double quotes such as "log" then I don't want to replace it.
3. Other than above 2 condition, I want to change it everywhere like this:

   ```
   log="log" ; // should be LOG="log";
   log.test(); // should be LOG.test();
   ```

I used below regular expression but it fulfilling my second and third condition but not first one:
[Link](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/6)

```
(\blog\b)(?=(?:[^\"]|[\"][^\"]*[\"])*$)
```

can someone please help me to how to proceed or fix it ?

Comment: i am using java pattern and matcher to execute my regular expression

Comment: but slog(?=[.=]) will not replace log.test("log"); to LOG.test("log");

Comment: Use `s.replaceAll("(?<!^import\\b.{0,1000})\\b(log)\\b(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*[\"])*$)", "LOG")`. See [demo here](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy29jp6r) (click *`Java`* button). It will work for cases where the distance between `import` and `log` is not more than 1000 symbols on a line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks , i will test it with my valid scenario , this is my first post to stackoverflow and very impression with the kind of responses i got .

Comment: If it works for you, please add the restriction of the distance between `import`  and `log`  to the question itself. I will be able to post an answer then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, added the restriction in question as its solving my purpose. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds to determine if it is surrounded by quotes.

[Like this](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/2) `(?<!")log(?!")`

or if lookarounds aren't supported in whatever language you're using,

[You can use this](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/5) `(?:[^"]|^)(log)(?:[^"]|$)`

Keep in mind if you use the 2nd one, you'll want to replace capture group 1, not the whole match. As you can see in my example it cuts the letter (or newline) before and after "log" if you use the full match.

Comment: Please post your regexps here, not just at regex101.com

Comment: its not fulfilling my first condition that it should not be changed if statement starts with import . like import test.log.try ; i dont want to replace here

Comment: @SandeepChauhan I'm going to assume you're using java because if the `import` statement. If you're reading line by line you can use this: `if(line.startsWith("import")) { continue; } else { /*run your pattern*/ }`

Comment: that is my last option to go line by line and check using if condition , i wanted to see if there is any way to handle these both condition using regular expression . As i am converting my entire file into `String fileContext = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file);`  and then replacing the logs or variable that i pass in string using regular expression . but it replacing the token into import statement also , that i dont want .

Answer (score 0):

Given your current requirements and restrictions, you may use the following Java regex compliant pattern:

```
s.replaceAll("(?<!^import\\b.{0,1000})\\b(log)\\b(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*[\"])*$)", "LOG")
```

See the [Java demo here](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy29jp6r).

**Details**

- `(?<!^import\\b.{0,1000})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if the current location is preceded with `import` and any 0 to 1000 symbols other than line break chars at the start of the string (or line if `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag is used)
- `\\b(log)\\b` - Group 1: `log` whole word
- `(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*[\"])*$)` - there should be no `"` chars or there may be any number of substrings inside two quotes right after `log`.